# JSON-ception - object inside object

Tags: php, json, forms

I would like to put urls in a JSON object or array if you will then put that in with some other singular fields for JSON.

> **JSON-ception** ( field1, field2, urls (url1, ... , url4), field3)

Once I get my urls how can I POST them with other fields in my form with the JSON-ception format.

```
$('form').submit(function() {

  var linksStr = $("#links").val();
  var urls = linksStr.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/[^\s]+/gi);

})
```

Then how would I best traverse these in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an object with all your fields and the url list, then post that via jQuery:

```
var formdata = {
     "field1": field1,
     "field2": field2,
     "urls": urls,
     "field3": field3
}
JSON.stringify(...)
$.ajax({ ... data: { matches : json }, ... })
```

And as to how you traverse them in PHP:

```
$json = json_decode($_GET["matches"]);
foreach ($json["urls"] as $url) {
    print $url;
}
```